# SwiftUI Swiping Component

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want a very simple swiping component in SwiftUI, similar to the swipe actions on TableView's or List's, but it should be generic for any kind of view over any other.

Comment: What is your question? This sounds like a request.

Comment: I just wanted to share my solution for a relatively common app component in case it might benefit anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code sample I wrote to generate the dummy app in this video recording.
[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var swipeOffset: CGFloat = 0

private let swipeButtonWidth: CGFloat = 60

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
        hiddenItem

        topItem
    }
    .animation(.default, value: swipeOffset)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .cornerRadius(12)
    .clipped(antialiased: true)
    .gesture(DragGesture()
        .onChanged { dragOffset in
            // Cap the offset to make sure it only slides to the left
            // and doesn't scroll past the hidden button.
            swipeOffset = min(0, max(-swipeButtonWidth, dragOffset.translation.width))
        }
        .onEnded { _ in
            // Optional - snap to either showing the button or not
            // when the user has finished swiping.
            if swipeOffset < -(swipeButtonWidth / 2) {
                swipeOffset = -swipeButtonWidth
            } else {
                swipeOffset = 0
            }
        })
}

var topItem: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("Any view you like :)")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .frame(height: 50)
    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    .background(Color.gray)
    .cornerRadius(12)
    .offset(x: swipeOffset)
}

var hiddenItem: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Secret Button!")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .frame(width: swipeButtonWidth, height: 50)
    .padding(.leading, 20)
    .background(Color.blue)
}
}
```